# systemd timer every 1 hour and X minutes?

Tags: systemd-timer

I'm looking for a systemd timer to run every 1 hour and 18 minutes but I have this only lead.

`systemd-analyze --iterations=3 calendar *:0/18` which is every 18 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a monotonic timer that runs at regular intervals (e.g. every X minutes and Y seconds, every X days and Y minutes etc) you have to define a starting point and a repetition value. This can be accomplished by using two directives in the `[Timer]` section.
The settings and their their starting points are explained in [`sytemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.timer.html#OnActiveSec=) man page which also mentions that

> Multiple directives may be combined of the same and of different
> types, in which case the timer unit will trigger whenever any of the
> specified timer expressions elapse. For example, by combining
> `OnBootSec=` and `OnUnitActiveSec=`, it is possible to define a timer
> that elapses in regular intervals and activates a specific service
> each time.

So, for a timer that runs every 1 hour and 18 minutes you could use something like:

```
[Timer]
Unit=test.service
AccuracySec=1s
OnActiveSec=5s
OnUnitActiveSec=1h 18min
```

In the above, the initial trigger is

> `OnActiveSec=`    Defines a timer relative to the moment the timer unit
> itself is activated.

and the repetition is done by

> `OnUnitActiveSec=`    Defines a timer relative to when the unit the timer
> unit is activating was last activated.

---

Note that for the time spans provided as arguments you can use any of the time units described in [`systemd.time`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.time.html#) man page which means that

```
OnUnitActiveSec=1h 18min
```

is the same as

```
OnUnitActiveSec=78m
```

or

```
OnUnitActiveSec=4680
```